# Trying to solve a quadratic equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have just started to use Matlab and I am struggling to solve quadratic equations. I am studying with the following guide:

> A guide to Matlab for beginners and experienced users

[Link to a preview.](https://www.mathworks.com/support/books/book96840.html)

I tried to solve the equation provided by the book (page 17). Despite typing exactly what the book instructed, I did not get the desired output. Note that firstly I tried with solve command and secondly with fzero but none worked out:

```
>> clear
>> syms x
>> solve ('x^2 - 2*x - 4 = 0')
Error using solve>getEqns (line 418)
List of equations must not be empty.

Error in solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

>> fzero ('x^2 - 2*x - 4 = 0')
Error using fzero (line 121)
FZERO requires at least two input arguments or a structure
with valid fields.
```

I do not understand the correction 'List of equations must not be empty' after using solve command. Besides, when I tried to use fzero command I got 'FZERO requires at least two input arguments or a structure with valid fields' which I did not get the hang of either. I looked for an alternative and I found x could be enclosed in parenthesis:

```
>> solve ('x^2 - 2*x - 4 = 0', x)
Error using solve>getEqns (line 418)
List of equations must not be empty.

Error in solve (line 226)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});
```

But again 'List of equations must not be empty' came as a result.
Please take into consideration the fact that I am a beginner and I understand this question may be too obvious to you, however I have been trying for a while and could not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming [this](https://www.amazon.com/Guide-MATLAB-Beginners-Experienced-2001-08-06/dp/B01MT4H2U7/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1532998130&sr=1-7&keywords=A+Guide+to+MATLAB%3A+For+Beginners+and+Experienced+Users) is the book you're referring to, it's outdated by about 17 years. [Much has changed since then](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R14SP2&endrelease=R2018a&rntype=incompatibility&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=).

Comment: A small hint for the future, if you get these type of problems, with a specific function, type: `help solve` (or whatever function is the problem) then you will see examples of how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following link, it looks like specifying your equation as a string (char vector) might be your issue. [Equations and systems solver in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html). In your situation, I would try the following:

```
clear
syms x
solve(x^2 - 2*x - 4 == 0, x);
```